# Is there a full tutorial for Queen vs Rook endgame?

Tags: endgame, queen-endgame

How do I convert the game into KQK easily, or simply mate? I've already learned the Philidor position.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no "easy" fool-proof method is known. It can take 31 moves until the
 checkmate or capture the rook with best blay from both side in the worst possible 
 initial position. Nevertheless, the queen can always win if the player with the rook
 has no perpetual check or a fast win of the queen or a stalemate trap.

In particular, you have to avoid stalemate traps. Human defence tends to lose faster
 because of the fear of putting the rook far away.

A difficult position is, for example W : Kd5, Qf7 S : Kd8, Rb6

where white has to find the counterintuitive move Qf4! which is not the only winning
 move but soon or later white must come to this idea to win.

Comment: That position is actually not difficult... However, it's hard to get in such positions.

Comment: The move Qf4 is very hard to recognize, if you do not know it.